# MySql - How get value in previous row and value in next row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table, named `Example`:

```
id(int 11) //not autoincriment
value (varchar 100)
```

It has the following rows of data:

```
0  100
2  150
3  200
6  250
7  300
```

Note that id values are not contiguous.

I've written this SQL so far:

```
SELECT * FROM Example WHERE id = 3
```

However, I don't know how to get the value of previous `id` and value of the next `id`...

Please help me get previous value and next value if `id` = 3 ?

*P.S.: in my example it will be: previous - `150`, next - `250`.*

Comment: Do you want the values in one row or 3 rows?

Comment: not the down voter, but what have you tried, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @SlyRaskal sorry, i update question now

Comment: @Bohemian for example i have id=3 (not autoincriment) an now i would like get value for previous `id` and value for next `id`.

Comment: I repeat my question: Do you want one row with 3 values or 3 rows each with one value?

Comment: Also, does this need to be in 1 query?  Also, does previous mean id-1 or previous?  e.g. if the id supplied is 4, can we just assume to return 3?  could there ever be a situation where there are ids 1,2,4,etc... ?

Comment: @Bohemian https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258557/get-prevision-next-record-in-one-row

Comment: SELECT (SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE id < 7 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as prev, (SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE id > 7 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) as next FROM TABLE LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 24):

Select the next row below:

```
SELECT * FROM Example WHERE id < 3 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Select the next row above:

```
SELECT * FROM Example WHERE id > 3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

Select both in one query, e.g. use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/union.html):

```
(SELECT * FROM Example WHERE id < 3 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
 UNION
(SELECT * FROM Example WHERE id > 3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1)
```

That what you mean?

Comment: This only works if you auto increment your id, which you shouldn't usually do unless you have a really good reason or if you need to build something very quickly and you don't care about silly things like security. /s lol

Answer (score 20):

A solution would be to use temporary variables:

```
select 
    @prev as previous,
    e.id,
    @prev := e.value as current
from
    (
        select
            @prev := null
    ) as i,
    example as e
order by
    e.id
```

To get the "next" value, repeat the procedure. Here is an example:

```
select 
  id, previous, current, next
from
  (
    select
      @next as next,
      @next := current as current,
      previous,
      id
    from
      (
        select @next := null
      ) as init,
      (
        select
          @prev as previous,
          @prev := e.value as current,
          e.id
        from
          (
            select @prev := null
          ) as init,
          example as e
        order by e.id
      ) as a
    order by
      a.id desc
  ) as b
order by
  id
```

Check [the example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a86b7/9)

May be overkill, but it may help you

Comment: thats a good one (y)

Comment: @Barranka It does not work anymore. You can check it on SQL Fiddle with MySQL 5.6. Previous and Next displays some Blob values instead of the correct values.

Comment: fixed it by replacing second line with:   `id, CONVERT(previous USING utf8), current, CONVERT(next USING utf8)`

Comment: Note that if the query somehow includes a group by the variable is evaluated differently and this won't work. You will need to wrap your query.

Answer (score 10):

please try this <kbd>[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f242b/4/0)</kbd>

```
SELECT value,
       (SELECT value FROM example e2
        WHERE e2.value < e1.value
        ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1) as previous_value,
       (SELECT value FROM example e3
        WHERE e3.value > e1.value
        ORDER BY value ASC LIMIT 1) as next_value
FROM example e1
WHERE id = 3
```

Edit: OP mentioned to grab value of previous `id` and value of next `id` in one of the comments so the code is here <kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f242b/5/0)</kbd>

```
SELECT value,
      (SELECT value FROM example e2
       WHERE e2.id < e1.id
       ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as previous_value,
      (SELECT value FROM example e3
       WHERE e3.id > e1.id
       ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) as next_value
FROM example e1
WHERE id = 3
```

Comment: Looks Very tedious, but actually it's the fastest..  I've compared it with other solutions here

Comment: Hmm, on my table with approx. 16000 rows, the alternative with variables is much much faster (MySQL 5.5 - 0.09s vs. 17s !)

Comment: This answer is more flexible.  You don't actually want to sort on ID anyhow.  I'm using UUID's which aren't sortable.  I can replace 'value' with 'sequence' and tighten up the inner selects to get the proper Prev/Next rows from Postgres.

Answer (score 6):

```sql
SELECT *,
       (SELECT value FROM example e1 WHERE e1.id < e.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) as prev_value,
       (SELECT value FROM example e2 WHERE e2.id > e.id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) as next_value
FROM example e
WHERE id=3;
```

And you can place your own offset after `OFFSET` keyword if you want to select records with higher offsets for next and previous values from the selected record.

Comment: @Strawberry Better answers are welcome at any time! (I had same question and I wanted the best working answer so finally I have found this answer working perfect in my case and I shared it here) hoping it helps somebody to find best answer easier.

Comment: If you say so. I think the top answer is better than this.

Comment: @Strawberry I respect your choice but in some situations (like when you want diff from two rows or calculations) my answer is more helpful to do calculations on the same row.

Comment: @Strawberry Assume the chapters of a book! What if you want to show number of pages in current chapter if you have a table with chapter_id and chapter_page_number for example! The formula to calculate this will be `next_chapter_page_number - chapter_page_number`. Still you use top answer? And if so then HOW?

Comment: If you have a question, suggest you ask a question - with proper DDLs and a desired result!

Comment: @Strawberry I just used an example of situation which is included in such question and yes maybe you're right to create a question with more details but I don't have question when I've got answers on my hand. I just shared my experience, maybe helpful for someone!

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution may suit you:

```
SELECT * FROM Example
WHERE id IN (
(SELECT MIN(id) FROM Example WHERE id > 3),(SELECT MAX(id) FROM Example WHERE id < 3)
)
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36c1d/2

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution if you need it all in one row

```
SELECT t.id, t.value, prev_id, p.value prev_value, next_id, n.value next_value
  FROM
(
  SELECT t.id, t.value,
  (
    SELECT id
      FROM table1
     WHERE id < t.id
     ORDER BY id DESC
     LIMIT 1
  ) prev_id,
  (
    SELECT id
      FROM table1
     WHERE id > t.id
     ORDER BY id
     LIMIT 1
  ) next_id
    FROM table1 t
   WHERE t.id = 3
) t LEFT JOIN table1 p
     ON t.prev_id = p.id LEFT JOIN table1 n
     ON t.next_id = n.id
```

Sample output:

```
| ID | VALUE | PREV_ID | PREV_VALUE | NEXT_ID | NEXT_VALUE |
|----|-------|---------|------------|---------|------------|
|  3 |   200 |       2 |        150 |       4 |        250 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a58b/10)** demo

Answer (score 1):

This query uses a user defined variable to calculate the distance from the target id, and a series of wrapper queries to get the results you want. Only one pass is made over the table, so it should perform well.

```
select * from (
    select id, value from (
        select *, (@x := ifnull(@x, 0) + if(id > 3, -1, 1)) row from (
            select * from mytable order by id
        ) x 
    ) y
    order by row desc
    limit 3
) z
order by id
```

See an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aab71e/10)

If you don't care about the final row order you can omit the outer-most wrapper query.

Comment: Question, how does `order by row` work when `row` is not in selected columns?

Comment: @ejay (in all databases) you can order by expressions that are not selected

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have an ID this has worked for me.

Next:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE column_name > current_column_data
ORDER BY column_name ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Previous:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE column_name < current_column_data
ORDER BY column_name DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I use this for a membership list where the search is on the last name of the  member. As long as you have the data from the current record it works fine.