# Mysql - Get the difference between two sequential values

Tags: mysql, sql, sequential

I want to get the difference between two sequential values from my table.

```
| id | count |
| 1  |   1   |
| 2  |   7   |
| 3  |   9   |
| 4  |   3   |
| 5  |   7   |
| 6  |   9   |
```

For example the difference between

*id2-id1 = 6,*
*id3-id2 = -2*,
 ...

How can I do it? `SELECT SUM(id(x+1) - id(x)) FROM table1`

Comment: You might want to see if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849098/mysql-how-get-value-in-previous-row-and-value-in-next-row will help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to find `count` for the preceding `id`.

In case there are no gaps in the `ID` column:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t.`id` ,' - ', t.`id` - 1) AS `IDs`
     , t.`count` - (SELECT `count`
                    FROM `tbl` 
                    WHERE `id` = t.`id` - 1) AS `Difference`
FROM `tbl` t 
WHERE t.`id` > 1
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/627d4/6)

In case there are gaps in the `ID`column.
*First solution*, using `ORDER BY <...> DESC` with `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t.id ,' - ', (SELECT `id` FROM tbl WHERE t.id > id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)) AS IDs
     , t.`count` - (SELECT `count` 
                    FROM tbl 
                    WHERE t.id > id
                    ORDER BY id DESC
                    LIMIT 1) AS difference
FROM tbl t
WHERE t.id > 1;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/754ead/6)

*Second solution*, using another subquery to find `count` with the `MAX(id)` less than current `id`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t.id ,' - ', (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM tbl WHERE id < t.id)) AS IDs
     , t.`count` - (SELECT `count`
                    FROM tbl
                    WHERE `id` = (SELECT MAX(`id`)
                                  FROM tbl
                                  WHERE id < t.id)
                   ) AS difference
FROM tbl t
WHERE t.id > 1;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/754ead/5)

*P.S. :* First column, `IDs`, is just for readability, you can omit it or change completely, if it is necessary.

Comment: but what if the ids have gaps

Answer (score 1):

If you *know* that the ids have no gaps, then just use a `join`:

```
select t.*, (tnext.count - t.count) as diff
from table t join
     table tnext
     on t.id = tnext.id - 1;
```

If you just want the sum of the differences, then that is the same as the last value minus the first value (all the intermediate values cancel out in the summation).  You can do this with `limit`:

```
select last.count - first.count
from (select t.* from table order by id limit 1) as first cross join
     (select t.* from table order by id desc limit 1) as last;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(count)-MIN(count) diff WHERE id IN(1,2)
```

Or this way

```
SELECT 2*STD(count) diff WHERE id IN(1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works even if **ids have distances between them**:

```sql
SELECT *, 
  ((SELECT value FROM example e2 WHERE e2.id > e1.id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) - value) as diff
FROM example e1;
```