# How do i optimise a mysql query that updates rank order in nested loop?

Tags: php, mysql

There is a score link table that holds a list of item_ids, the category_ids they are assigned to, and a score.

**What I am trying to do is**
For each category, grab all the items assigned to it, ordered by highest score first.
This then defines that items RANK ORDER in that category.

I then want to store that items RANK in the same table against the matching item_id and category_id.

This works great with the PHP MySQL code i have, but unfortunately there are 10000 categories and so takes about 30mins before timing out.

Here is an example of what im doing:

```
SELECT category_id FROM tbl_categories  /* - this just grabs a list of categorys to loop through */

Loop through each row returned {

    SELECT item_id, score 
    FROM tbl_scores 
    WHERE category_id = CATEGORY_ID ORDER BY score DESC
    MYCOUNT = 0

    Loop through each results, incrementing the count and storing in another tables {

      MYCOUNT = MYCOUNT + 1
      UPDATE tbl_scores 
      SET rank = MYCOUNT 
      WHERE item_id = ITEMID AND category_id = CATEGORYID

    }

}
```

Comment: Look into using session variables as counters , as explained here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728413/equivalent-of-oracle-s-rowid-in-mysql

I think you can achieve what you wanted with a single join statement and counter variable.

Comment: I assumed it could be done with a single join and counter. I did look into using the counters as row_number is not available in MySQL but not sure how to create the singe update statement.

I would appreciated an example of how to go about this as my head has started to turn to mush :)

Comment: can you give us sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com/ and the output that you want

Comment: Here is the sql fiddle for the initial example result set http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca9a95 - the script i have would pull out all the items for a specific category, ordered by score - then would loop through using a counter to set the rank column - the output i would expect is here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39f49a/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query to get the rank for each product (using session variables, see more info here [MySql - How get value in previous row and value in next row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849098/mysql-how-get-value-in-previous-row-and-value-in-next-row))

```
SELECT          
    s.categoryid    ,       
    s.itemid,       
    s.score,        
    @rowid := IF (@prev_categroy = s.categoryid, @rowid+1, 0),
    @prev_categroy := s.categoryid AS curr  
FROM scores s, (SELECT @rowid:=0, @prev_categroy := NULL) AS init   
ORDER BY s.categoryid, s.score DESC
```

I would store the results of this (ranks) in a temporary table and then update in another statement with a simple join by item_id, supposing the size of the table is not huge.

Comment: That was amazingly helpful, and worked great. Thanks a lot.