# Get Prevision Next record in ONE ROW

Tags: mysql, select

---

I want get prev\next id in one row. If not value for next or prev rec its must be NULL.

```
mysql> select picsid  from pics where  albid_pics=15;
+--------+
| picsid |
+--------+
|    110 |
|    111 |
|    112 |
|    113 |
|    114 |
|    115 |
|    116 |
|    117 |
|    131 |
|    132 |
|    133 |
|    134 |
|    135 |
|    136 |
|    153 |
|    154 |
|    155 |
|    156 |
|    157 |
|    159 |
|    160 |
+--------+
21 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

### 1. if i do

```
(select picsid prv from pics where picsid<136 and albid_pics=15 order by prv desc limit 1)
union
(select picsid nxt from pics where picsid>136 and albid_pics=15 order by nxt asc limit 1);
+-----+
| prv |
+-----+
| 135 |
| 153 |
+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

But i want get qresult in 1 row,

### 2.

```
mysql> (select picsid prv from pics where picsid<160 and albid_pics=15 order by prv desc limit 1)  union  (select picsid nxt from pics where picsid>160 and albid_pics=15 order by nxt asc limit 1);
+-----+
| prv |
+-----+
| 159 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

If not value for next or prev record its must be NULL.

### Whst this make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is quite simple. For instance, this:

```
SELECT (1+1) AS sum1,(2+2) AS sum2
```

will result in:

```
+------+------+
| sum1 | sum2 |
+------+------+
|    2 |    4 |
+------+------+
```

All you have to do is put your subqueries in there:

```
SELECT (SELECT picsid 
        FROM pics 
        WHERE picsid < 136 AND 
              albid_pics = 15 
        ORDER BY picsid DESC 
        LIMIT 1) AS previous,
        (SELECT picsid 
        FROM pics 
        WHERE picsid > 136 AND 
              albid_pics = 15 
        ORDER BY picsid ASC 
        LIMIT 1) AS `next`;
```

Note: `next` is a keyword in MySQL, hence the backticks.

Comment: wow, it was so simple!
but I have been tormented for several hours :(
and I know about `AS`

Comment: Simple things can often be the most difficult ones to find, since they are hardly ever mentioned anywhere.